# Phpunit, how to remove mock objects?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have two different testcases, both puts a mock on a method. Is there a way to clean up mocked objects? Because there are different expectations in the testmethods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be you need use `Mock::close()`:

```
...    
public function tearDown()
{
    Mockery::close();
}
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Create (or recreate) the mock in a test method itself, rather than trying to re-use a pre-generated object (presumably in some kind of setUp function) if it's not suitable for your needs.

Comment: you mean the "$stub = $this->getMock ...." ? This is how I do, I create it in every testmethod

Comment: If you are creating the $stub in every test function, it will be destroyed at the end of the function, unless you are doing something quite odd.

Comment: hmmm yea I know, somehow it still behaves unexpectedly. If we look at the source code of Phpunit, into getMock(), we can see a "$this->mockObjects[]" thing, and I cant see the way to erase this array

Comment: It may be helpful to create a minimal set of code that demonstrates the issue.